# How to find out if (especially foreign) movies are uncut

Tags: distribution, film-industry

The reason I ask is that it was especially notable
for foreign films that scenes are cut mercilessly
so that they fit in the "common" 90 min format.

For example: ["Tom-Yum-Goong"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom-Yum-Goong).

Even in cinema it was obvious that key scenes were
cut out (Severals murders, the interaction with the police
officers, the freeing and escape of Mark and Khorn).

If I find a movie good, I absolutely do not mind to see
it even if it lasts 4 hours. It is not a question about
censorship and violence, it is more that I take offense
that a movie is maimed because it does not fit in the
western standard length.

First question:
**How do you find out how long the uncut/director cut version is?**

No, let me google that for you *does not work*:

[German Wikipedia: 90 min](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revenge_of_the_Warrior_%E2%80%93_Tom_Yum_Goong)
[English Wikipedia: 110 min](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom-Yum-Goong)
[Thai Wikipedia: 105 min](https://th.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%B8%95%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%A1%E0%B8%A2%E0%B8%B3%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B8%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%87_(%E0%B8%A0%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%9E%E0%B8%A2%E0%B8%99%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%A3%E0%B9%8C))

Comment: Recommendation questions asking for movies/TV-shows or resources to locate or watch movie/TV content are off topic

Comment: @Paulie_D Adjusted by removing the question how to locate or watch a movie.

Comment: IMDB often has an 'Alternate versions' section, which will sometimes list differences between versions shown in different regions. However, it's dependent on users adding such content.  For this movie (known as The Protector in the US), there's actually a relevant answer in the IMDB FAQ: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0427954/faq